# Wrong function called in AngularJS directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have two similar directives, where I want to run validators for specific files (it isn't the best practice, I know, since it is not based on DRY principle. But I am just learning AngularJS).

`module.js`

```
var $moduleExample = angular.module("$moduleExample", ["ngMaterial"]);

$moduleExample.controller("testController", [
    "$scope",
    function (
        $scope,
    ) {
        $scope.fileDialog = function () {
            var el = angular.element("#file-dialog");
            el.trigger('click');
        };
    }
]);

$moduleExample.directive("validJson", function jsonValidFile() {
    var validFormats = ['json'];
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {
            elem.on('change', function () {
                var value = elem.val(),
                    ext = value.substring(value.lastIndexOf('.') + 1).toLowerCase();
                scope.isModelValid = validFormats.indexOf(ext) !== -1;
            });
        }
    };
});
$moduleExample.directive("validImage", function imageValidFile() {
    var validFormats = ['jpg'];
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {
            elem.on('change', function () {
                var value = elem.val(),
                    imageValue = attrs.validImage,
                    ext = value.substring(value.lastIndexOf('.') + 1).toLowerCase();
                scope.isImageValid = validFormats.indexOf(ext) !== -1;
            });
        }
    };
});
```

`template.html`

```
<div>
    <md-button ng-click="fileDialog();">
        <md-icon md-font-set="material-icons">file_upload</md-icon>
        upload json
    </md-button>
    <input id="file-dialog" type="file" class="ng-hide" valid-image on-file-change="handleImageFile" ng-model="image" />
</div>
<div>
    <md-button ng-click="fileDialog();">
        <md-icon md-font-set="material-icons">file_upload</md-icon>
        upload image
    </md-button>
    <input id="file-dialog" type="file" class="ng-hide" valid-json on-file-change="handleJsonFile" ng-model="model" />
</div>
```

The second button should validate the correct `json` format, but instead of valid-json, the valid-image directive's function is called and is validated against `jpg`.

The handleImageFile and handleJsonFile function are only reading the files.

What am I missing?

Comment: avoid using `.change` - use watch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the fileDialog function I referred to the file-dialog element. Since I had the same identifier and function on both directives, it made the confusion.